# How do I use SYN cookies to perform a DOS attack

Tags: network, attack-prevention, server, ddos, denial-of-service

I am taking a computer security course but I have a question I am stuck on.

***You are the system administrator for a provider that owns a large network (e.g., at least 64,000 IP addresses). Show how you can use SYN cookies to perform a DOS attack on a web server.***

I am confused by this though because I thought that SYN cookies were used to prevent SYN flood attacks so I cannot figure out how they can be used to perform or exploit an attack.

**I know there is already a similar post for this question but it was almost 10 years old and didn't really provide any helpful answer.**

Comment: This does look exactly like [Using SYN cookies to perform a DOS attack](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20904/using-syn-cookies-to-perform-a-dos-attack). And you seem to acknowledge that this question already exists, only that you don't find the answers helpful. But the answers there are actually helpful in that they support your position in that SYN cookies are more a protection than a threat, but that there are some trade-offs.